# How can I know if a email is sent correctly with Django/Python?

Tags: python, django

I need know that if a email is sent correctly for to do several operations but the function always return True.

Any idea?

Thanks you.

Comment: Have you written any code yet? Please share it if you have. That way we can help you from there.

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to check that a mail has actually been received. This is not because of a failing in Django, but a consequence of the way email works.

If you need some form of definite delivery confirmation, you need to use something other than email.

Comment: Did anything change in 2019? Or still there is no way of checking it?

Answer (score 9):

When running unit tests emails are stored as [EmailMessage](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage) objects in a list at [`django.core.mail.outbox`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.core.mail.django.core.mail.outbox) you can then perform any checks you want in your test class. Below is an example from [django's docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#e-mail-services).

```
from django.core import mail
from django.test import TestCase

class EmailTest(TestCase):
    def test_send_email(self):
        # Send message.
        mail.send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.',
            'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False)

        # Test that one message has been sent.
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)

        # Verify that the subject of the first message is correct.
        self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Subject here')
```

Alternatively if you just want to visually check the contents of the email during development you can set the [`EMAIL_BACKEND`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#e-mail-backends) to:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

and then look at you console.

or

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/app-messages' # change this to a proper location
```

then check the file.

Comment: I can't find tmp/app-messages or anything created. Where am I supposed to find that folder?

And what console do you mean? In my terminal when I use the console backend there are no prints...

Answer (score 3):

[This post](http://www.rossp.org/blog/2010/jun/11/django-bounces-postmark/) on integrating Django with [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) describes how you can follow-up on e-mail delivery.

Comment: Linking to external answers is discouraged because the external sites can change, making the answer unavailable or irrelevant.  Linking to a commercial service without clarifying that is an even bigger disservice.

Answer (score 2):

In case of error, [send_mail](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) should raise an exception. The fail_silently argument makes possible to ignore the error. Did you enable this option by mistake?

I hope it helps

Comment: This exception indicate if the mail is good written. ie: try@com return a raise exception but fsaaadadsadfsafds@try.com no, although this mail dont exist.